# Cookies.get() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, session-cookies, js-cookie

I am using the `js-cookie` package to store and handle cookies in my react app. The cookie is set when the user first logs in and is visible in the Applications tab in the browser. I created a service that adds new products to the database, the cookie stores the jwt token which is then passed to the backend for verification before the user does anything. the Cookies.get() method always returns undefined within this service.

Here the code for the service

```
import axios from 'axios'
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import { ProductTypes } from '../domain/entities/Product';
import { addProductResponse, getProductResponse } from '../domain/responses/productResponse';

const token = Cookies.get("authToken");
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/',
  headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
          "Authorization":`Bearer ${token}`
        },
});


export const addProduct = async(formValues:ProductTypes):Promise<addProductResponse>=>{
  console.log("token from react",token);
  
    return await instance.post(`/products/create-product`,formValues).then(
        (response:addProductResponse) => response)

}
```

This is how it is being set

```
 const setToken = (authToken: string) => {
      Cookies.set("authToken", authToken, {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000),
        secure: true,
      });
    };
```

Can someone kindly point out to me what i may doing wrong?
PS: It is a Typescript application

Comment: What kind of cookie is it? SameSite, etc.? Also, are you able to get any cookie other cookies, or have you only tried it with this one?

Comment: I am able to get the same cookie in a React component. But not in the service file

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you are adding `secure: true` parameter in `Cookies.set` function and calling `baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/'` without `HTTPS` protocol, that's the reason. So, you just need to set `secure: false`

> The Secure attribute limits the scope of the cookie to "secure" channels (where "secure" is defined by the user agent). When a cookie has the Secure attribute, the user agent will include the cookie in an HTTP request only if the request is transmitted over a secure channel (typically HTTP over Transport Layer Security (TLS) [RFC2818]).

Comment: It didnt seem to work. Could it be the js-cookie package?